# Server and client data send() and recv() issue

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv

I have been trying to write a client and server program using C socket programming that does 2 tasks

1. On prompted from server -> OS command is executed in client machine
2. Output is stored in a file which is sent back to server. Where server reads it and displays the data plus writes the data in a file on server side.

**Issue**
When client sends file to the server, server does not display whole data and looks like recv() keeps waiting on socket.

Need some help

Here's the code

**server code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define SIZE 1024

void write_file(char *filename,int sockfd){
  int n;
  FILE *fp ;
  char buffer[SIZE] ;
  
  fp = fopen(filename, "w");
  while (1) {
    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0);
    if (n <= 0){
      break;
      return;
    }
    printf("%s", buffer) ;
    fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    bzero(buffer, SIZE);
  }
  fclose(fp) ;
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  
  int portno = 7416;
  int e,n,n1;
  char *cmd ;
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  struct hostent *server;
  char *fle = "/tmp/reposvr.";
  FILE *fp;
  char *num ;
  
  
  if (argc < 3) {
     fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname command \n", argv[0]);
     exit(0);
  }
  cmd=argv[2] ;
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sockfd < 0) {
    perror("[-]Error in socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("[+]Server socket created successfully.\n");
  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

  //server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  //server_addr.sin_port = port;
  //server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  
  bzero((char *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)server->h_addr);
  memset(server_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof server_addr.sin_zero);

  e = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  if(e == -1) {
    perror("[-]Error in socket");
    exit(1);
  }
    printf("[+]Connected to Server.\n");
    
   n = write(sockfd, cmd , strlen(cmd));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
     
    char *filename=NULL;
    filename = (char*)malloc( 50 * sizeof(char) ) ;
    strcpy(filename,fle );
     
    n1=rand();   

    if (asprintf(&num, "%d", n1) == -1) {
        perror("asprintf");
    } else {
        strcat(filename, num);
        printf("%s\n", filename);
        free(num);
    }
     printf("%s\n",filename) ;
  

  write_file(filename,sockfd) ;
  printf("[+]File data sent successfully.\n");

    printf("[+]Closing the connection.\n");
  close(sockfd);

  return 0;
}
```

**Client code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define SIZE 1024

void send_file(FILE *fp, int sockfd){
  int n;
  char data[SIZE] = {0};

  while(fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
    if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1) {
      perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
      exit(1);
    }
    bzero(data, SIZE);
  }
}

int main(){
  int port = 7416;
  int e,n1, n ;  
  FILE *fp ;
  char filename[50] = "/tmp/gateway." ;
  char command[50];
  char *num;
  FILE *pf;
  char data[SIZE];
  int sockfd, new_sock;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr, new_addr;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  char buffer[SIZE];

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sockfd < 0) {
    perror("[-]Error in socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("[+]Server socket created successfully.\n");

  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  e = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  if(e < 0) {
    perror("[-]Error in bind");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("[+]Binding successfull.\n");

  if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){
        printf("[+]Listening....\n");
    }else{
        perror("[-]Error in listening");
    exit(1);
    }

  addr_size = sizeof(new_addr);
  while ( new_sock = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&new_addr, &addr_size) )
  {   
       printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",
              inet_ntoa(new_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(new_addr.sin_port));
              
       n = read(new_sock,buffer,1024);
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     
         strcpy(command, buffer) ;
         printf("%s",command) ;
         pf = popen(command,"r");
         bzero(data,1024);
        n1=rand();   
         
    

    if (asprintf(&num, "%d", n1) == -1) {
        perror("asprintf");
    } else {
        strcat(filename, num);
        printf("%s\n", filename);
        free(num);
    }
     printf("%s",filename) ;
     fp=fopen(filename,"w" );
     while (fgets(data, 2048, pf) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", data);
        fprintf(fp, "%s",data) ;
        }
        fclose(fp) ;
      fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("[-]Error in reading file.");
    exit(1);
  }
  
   send_file(fp, new_sock);
   printf("[+]Data written in the file successfully.\n");
  }
  
  

  return 0;
  
}
```

**Execution output**
[image]

**Edit**

Based on the suggestions in this forum, I increased SIZE to 2048 and found that now it returns less rows and hangs after 4-5 rows itself.  This is weird. I am sure it's not because of SIZE.

If you see, in client side, we are able to successfully write all in a file. Second part of the program is to read from file and send it to server. Here I am iterating through whole file and sending the data to server. The data send loop is working nicely as I have printf in same loop and we can see all data getting printed.

Looking at server side, here also we are looping till number of bytes read are < 1. Theoretically, this should work. I am sure there's some tiny silly thing that I am missing. Just not able to put my finger on it. Really need some insights in here.

**Edit 2**
Already tried SIZE , MSG_PEEK as you can see in comments. Any more suggestions ?

Comment: If you read the description of those functions it's stated that they do not gauruntee sending the entire buffer or recieving the entire buffer. It's your job to check the size, increment the pointer and offset the size accordingly after each call and check for errors.

Comment: ``if (send(sockfd, data, sizeof(data)`` try put SIZE value to 2048 in server side. You are sending sizeof(data) but recv 1024.. ``n = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0);``

Comment: If you don't want change the SIZE value, you can recv again the information not getted with: If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and **MSG_PEEK** is not set in the flags argument, the excess bytes shall be discarded. (MSG_PEEK
Peeks at an incoming message. The data is treated as unread and the next recv() or similar function shall still return this data.) Source: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html

Comment: Your server is a client and your client is a server.

Comment: @Rjain use MSG_PEEK flag in recv function.

Comment: Typically the propper way to send data and how it's usually done is to send a constant size header that your client/server reads. The constant size header typically includes the type of data being sent/received as well as the total size to read. For example in http headers there's a content-length field. Usually games will send fixed packet sizes as well.

Comment: @AlumnoCabreado  I tried MSG_PEEK and an interesting thing happened. It went into endless loop on first line.  It not only displayed the first line ( which you can see from the output shared earlier is "total 364" ) rather wrote same in file also.  I am still trying to understand what just happened.

Comment: But shows all data ?

Comment: Actually no. Just the first line.  total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
total 364
.......

Comment: @Nina. Is it like you precalculate the size of the data, send it to server and have server recv() data with that size  ? Well, that's a good idea. Gotta give it a try.  But does that work in file operations also  ? Any example that you might have handy ?

Comment: @Rjain have you check the length you send and the length you receive ?